# How to implement Init() with no parameters? Enum using Generics. Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics, enums, linked-list

I've got a Linked List implementation. And I wonder if that's possible to have init() with no parameters given the fact that I'm using generics. Currently I have an error "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred"

```
indirect enum LinkedList<T> {
    
    case Empty
    case Node(value: T, next: LinkedList<T>)
    
    init() {
        self = .Empty
        
    }
    init(value: T) {
        self = .Node(value: value, next: .Empty)
    }
    
}
```

**What I can do**

```
var list = LinkedList<String>.Node(value: "1", next: .Empty)
var list2 = LinkedList(value: 5)
```

**What I want to do**

```
var list = LinkedList()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift is a type-inferred language. So, the compiler needs to know what the type is, and with an empty `init` there's nothing to infer the type from.

So you have multiple options to help the compiler:

```
// explicitly specify the type of the variable
let list1: LinkedList<Int> = .init()

// or use type casting
let list2 = LinkedList() as LinkedList<Int>
```

Alternatively, pass the type as a parameter to `init`. So, instead of an empty `init()`, create an `init` with a default type value, so in cases where it could be otherwise inferred it could still be empty:

```
init(_ t: T.Type = T.self) {
   self = .Empty
}
```

```
let list3a = LinkedList(Int.self)

let list3b: LinkedList<Int> = .init() // still works
```

---

Unrelated, but I suggest keeping up with Swift conventions and name variables/properties with camelCase, and types - with CapitalCase, so your enum ought to be:

```
indirect enum LinkedList<T> {
    case empty
    case node(value: T, next: LinkedList<T>)
    // ...
}
```